# How to export layers from exr using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an EXR that has multiple layers in it:

[image]

Now I am trying to export each of these layers into separate images using FFMPEG. I would also be happy with exporting them into a video or anything like that.

I have tried:

`{ffmpeg} -i "{input.exr}" -layer "specular" "{output.exr}"`
Codec AVOption layer (Set the decoding layer) specified for output file #0 () is not an encoding option.

`{ffmpeg} -i "{input.exr}" -layer "specular.red" "{output.exr}"`
Codec AVOption layer (Set the decoding layer) specified for output file #0 () is not an encoding option.

`{ffmpeg} -layer "specular" -i "{input.exr}"  "{output.exr}"`
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input

Any other ideas? I'm lost here...